# Debug console in VS Code with Angular/Typescipt not showing source mapped debug info

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have an Angular (10) project which I'm debugging from VS Code. I have sourcemaps: true everywhere and I'm able to debug and set breakpoints.

However, in the debug console in VS Code, if I have an error, it doesn't show me line numbers from the sourcemap. If I look in the Chrome debug tools, it does show me the source mapped error e.g. the typescript file and line number, in VS Code I just see main.js e.g.

Chrome console:

[image: Chrome console output]

VS Code:

[image: VS Code debug console]

Is there a way I can get VS Code debug console to give me the better source mapped output? Here's my launch.json config for debugging in Chrome:

```js
{
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Chrome on CLI serve",
    "url": "http://localhost:4201",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No, and bizarrely it works fine in some of my projects and not others

Comment: Same here - some projects this works and not others.  Right now I have a project that I started by copying another project. The original project works fine, the new project does not.  Makes no sense.